# Securing IIS AppPool identity password

Tags: iis, application-pool

Context:
I'm trying to use a custom windows account for application pool, and enable Oracle OS authentication so that we would not have to store DB username and password in a config file.

Problem:
This setup works, however, I've noticed that I am able to 'recover' password using `appcmd.exe`. Is there a way to make sure someone with administrative and physical access cannot read the password in plain text?

This is a Windows 2016 machine, IIS 10. Password *looks* encrypted when looking into `applicationHost.config` file.
Following command shows the password:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list apppool "ImoAppPool" /text:*
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS application pool identity account passwords shown in clear text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706273/iis-application-pool-identity-account-passwords-shown-in-clear-text)